# Get Libraries from package-lock.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, npm, libraries

I need to get all the libraries and versions of the package-lock.json.

To give context. I'm running a security module inside a jenkins that is responsible for making an inventory of libraries for each application. The idea is to bring all the parent versions with your own requires.

For example:

```html
{
  "name": "node-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "requires": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "accepts": {
      "version": "1.3.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/accepts/-/accepts-1.3.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-hiRnWMfdbSGmR0/whKR0DsBesh8=",
      "requires": {
        "mime-types": "~2.1.16",
        "negotiator": "0.6.1"
      }
    }
}
```

From this package we need to take out and build a json with:
a list of libraries like this:

```html
libraries: [
{libName: "accepts" , libVersion: "1.3.4" parent: null}
{libName: "mime-types", libVersion: "~2.1.16", parent: "accepts"}
{libName: "negotiator", libVersion: "0.6.1", parent: "accepts}
]
```

One more detail, being a jenkins I need to run the script that does this in bash. They know if there is already something built that is similar

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I assumed you are looking for node solution, seeing the `nodejs` tag. Luckily node can natively require json files. Once we get the data from `package-lock.json` we can easily extract the data:

```js
const lockJson = require('./package-lock.json'); // edit path if needed

const libraries = [];

// Loop through dependencies keys (as it is an object)
Object.keys(lockJson.dependencies).forEach((dependencyName) => {
  const dependencyData = lockJson.dependencies[dependencyName];

  libraries.push({
    libName: dependencyName,
    libVersion: dependencyData.version,
    parent: null,
  });

  // Loop through requires subdependencies      
  if (dependencyData.requires) {
    Object.keys(dependencyData.requires).forEach((subdependencyName) => {
      const subdependencyVersion = dependencyData.requires[subdependencyName];

      libraries.push({
        libName: subdependencyName,
        libVersion: subdependencyVersion,
        parent: dependencyName,
      });
    });
  }
});

console.log(libraries);
```

Save this as `convert.js` and run it by using `node convert.js`.

Hope that helps, cheers!